# Firefox Mousemove event.which

Tags: javascript, drawing, html5-canvas

I'm writing an HTML5 canvas drawing app, and I need to be able to tell whether or not the left mouse button is pressed down during a mousemove event. On Chrome, this works:

```
if (event.which == 1) { <do stuff> }
```

But in FireFox, event.which *always* is 1, no matter whether or not the button is pressed.

How can I detect whether the mouse button is pressed during a mousemove event?

Comment: try what you want to do with in onmousedown event not in the onmousemove event :)

Comment: Well, I currently have a solution where I set a variable (is_drawing) to true on the mousedown event and then set it to false on the mouseup/mouseout event. But I don't like this 'cause if the mouse leaves the canvas and then comes back, the drawing doesn't restart until you click again. So a real solution would be a real help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, you can't. MDN, for example, [explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/More_Event_Handlers):

> When a mouse button event occurs, a number of additional properties
>   are available to determine which mouse buttons were pressed and the
>   location of the mouse pointer. The event's button property can be used
>   to determine which button was pressed, where possible values are 0 for
>   the left button, 1 for the middle button and 2 for the right button.
>   If you've configured your mouse differently, these values may be
>   different.
>
> ...
>
> The button and detail properties only apply to the mouse button
>   related events, not mouse movement events. For the mousemove event,
>   for example, both properties will be set to 0.

If you want, you can set global `mousedown` and `mouseup` handlers that set flags appropriately and then at any given point in time you can with relative degree of accuracy determine if/which mouse button is pressed.

Answer (score 7):

You should use a variable to hold the state of the mousedown.
When you `mousedown` on the canvas set it to true, and when you `mouseup` on the document set it to false..

This way it will be cleared wherever you click..

Something like this

```
var isMouseDown = false;

var draw = document.getElementById('draw');

document.addEventListener('mouseup',
                          function(){
                              isMouseDown = false;
                          },
                          false);

draw.addEventListener('mousedown',
                      function(e){
                          e.preventDefault(); // cancel element drag..
                          isMouseDown = true;
                      },
                      false);

draw.addEventListener('mousemove',
                      function(e){
                          if (isMouseDown){
                              // do the drawing ..
                          }
                      },
                      false);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8JbaX/

Comment: Right, this is what I'm currently doing. I had hoped for a better solution, but if this is all I can do, I guess it is. :P

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can check `event.buttons` on Firefox which tells you if left button, right button or none are pressed. You will need an if-statement to differentiate with Chrome which doesn't have `event.buttons`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this pseudo-polyfill to avoid FireFox mouseMove problems:

```
function fixWhich(e) {
    if (!e.which && e.button) { // if no which, but button (IE8-)
        if (e.button & 1)
            e.which = 1; // left
        else if (e.button & 4)
            e.which = 2; // middle
        else if (e.button & 2)
            e.which = 3; // right

    }
    if (e.buttons) { //if there's buttons, i set new option buttondown (FF)
        if (e.buttons & 1)
            e.buttondown = 1; // left
        else if (e.buttons & 4)
            e.buttondown = 2; // middle
        else if (e.buttons & 2)
            e.buttondown = 3; // right

    }
}
```

I call it "pseudo" because, it forces me to check the button down while moving this way:

```
if (e.buttondown === 1) {
        //do anything
    }
```

Instead of normal:

```
if (e.which === 1) {
       //do anything
    }
```